# Swift - How to set up config variables for multiple targets in XCode Project

Tags: swift, configuration, standards, xcode8, targets

I'm starting a [white label app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-label_product) to use for many clients (Targets). Targets share functionalities but have different values for global variables such as services URLs, names, cosmetics, etc.

In Obj-C I would use a Constants.h file for each target and ***#macros*** but since the project is Swift 3 native I don't know what would be the best approach.

If I use different **.plist files** for each target, I have to redefine settings manually that I prefer to stay the same between targets like CFBundleVersion, some permissions, etc.

In these configurations I need to set some arrays and dictionaries so I don't know if using **.xconfig files** is the best approach either.

So, if anyone has faced something similar in Swift and can explain his approach it would be much appreciated.